# How to use scalaz' ContT monad transformer to implement a while loop

Tags: monads, scalaz, monad-transformers, scalaz7

I'm trying to understand how to use the `ContT` monad transformer in Scalaz 7 to implement a `while` loop in a functional way while preventing stack overflows. A simple example illustrating the usage of `ContT` would be very helpful.

Comment: Rather than using `ContT` for implementing a while loop in a functional way I came across scalaz' `Monad.whileM_`. While this seems to work fine in general, I still need to sort out stack safety: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652980/trampolining-scalaz-monad-whilem-to-prevent-stack-overflow