# Trampolining scalaz' Monad.whileM_ to prevent stack overflow

Tags: monads, scalaz, scalaz7, trampolines

I'm using scalaz' `Monad.whileM_` to implement a while loop in a functional way as follows:

```
object Main {

  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._

  import scala.language.higherKinds

  case class IState(s: Int)

  type IStateT[A] = StateT[Id, IState, A]
  type MTransT[S[_], A] = EitherT[S, String, A]
  type MTrans[A] = MTransT[IStateT, A]

  def eval(k: Int): MTrans[Int] = {
    for {
      state <- get[IState].liftM[MTransT]
      _ <- put(state.copy(s = (state.s + 1) % k)).liftM[MTransT]
    } yield (k + 1)
  }

  def evalCond(): MTrans[Boolean] = {
    for {
      state <- get[IState].liftM[MTransT]
    } yield (state.s != 0)
  }


  def run() = {
    val k = 10
    eval(k).whileM_(evalCond()).run(IState(1))
  }
}
```

While this works for small `k`, it results in a StackOverflow error for large `k` (e.g. 1000000). Is there a way to trampoline `whileM_` or is there a better way to be stack safe?

Answer (score 2):

Use `scalaz.Free.Trampoline` instead of `scalaz.Id.Id`.

```
type IStateT[A] = StateT[Trampoline, IState, A]
```

The state operations used here return `State[S, A]` which is just an alias for `StateT[Id, S, A]`. You need to use the `lift[M[_]]` function defined on `StateT` to lift `StateT[Id, S, A]` to `StateT[Trampoline, S, A]`.

```
def eval(k: Int): MTrans[Int] = {
  for {
    state <- get[IState].lift[Trampoline].liftM[MTransT]
    _ <- put(state.copy(s = (state.s + 1) % k)).lift[Trampoline].liftM[MTransT]
  } yield (k + 1)
}

def evalCond(): MTrans[Boolean] = {
  for {
    state <- get[IState].lift[Trampoline].liftM[MTransT]
  } yield (state.s != 0)
}
```

Finally, calling `.run(IState(1))` now results in `Trampoline[(IState, String \/ Unit)]`. You must additionally `run` this as well.

```
eval(k).whileM_(evalCond()).run(IState(1)).run
```

Comment: The monad stack is given in my case. Is there a way to lift things into a trampoline locally without having to modify the monad stack?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible or not. You will probably have better luck asking your question to the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scalaz